# new Date().toLocaleString not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox

In json response i am getting date in GMT format like this **2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111** . Whenever i am trying to convert into local date /time format using following code :-

```
new Date('2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111').toLocaleString()
```

I am getting output like this :-

**Chrome**

```
"09/03/2016, 15:25:47"   Which is correct
```

**Mozilla Firefox**

```
"3/9/2016, 9:55:47 AM"  Which is wrong
```

new Date('2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111').toLocaleString() is not working on Firefox .

Comment: You're not telling `Date` which time zone to convert _from_, which means it's all a hairy mess what the javascript engines do about it :-/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson hi but it's working fine in chrome

Comment: @Rushikeshjogle It is not working "fine" in Chrome, either. No specification defines what date should result in the date string you are using. Chrome just happens to interpret it the way you think is correct. However, that behaviour might be different in older or newer versions of Chrome. You should either use a standard date string or parse it correctly.

Comment: The subject in this question should be *"toLocaleString on firefox produces bad result"*. And then in the text of the question: *"I don't define what timezone should be"*. And voilà, a self-answered question will be!!

Comment: And no one is going to point out that the format is wrong irregardless of the timezone. Chrome shows times in 24-hour format (likely an OS setting) while FireFox shows 12-hour with AM formatting.—Nevermind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521561/javascript-date-tolocaletimestring-doesnt-match-computers-time-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MDN specification of Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), "dateString" can be either IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps or a version of ISO8601. Your date string is neither of it. I'm not even sure what "107111" in the end of your string should be, so how should a computer figure that out?

In general, it is always advisable to use date strings in the format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ".

Answer (score 1):

In js file you write

```
$scope.date=new Date('2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111');
```

in html file you write

```
{{date | date :'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss'}}
```

it will working any browser

Comment: That won't work. When not even the browser is able to interpret the date string, how should Angular be able to properly format it?

Comment: Check below link for more details about Mozilla localization concept
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 0):

You can always specify the localization by passing it to the toLocaleString function.
for example:

```
new Date('2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111').toLocaleString("en-GB");
```

Will result in:

```
09/03/2016, 11:55:47
```

in both Chrome & Firefox.

Be aware:

```
new Date('2016-03-09T09:55:47.107111').toLocaleString("en-GB");

new Date('2016-03-09 09:55:47.107111').toLocaleString("en-GB");
```

will give you different time output (first will add the locale difference from UTC, the second won't.

Comment: This is just wrong. Neither is it the same on the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome (in my timezone at least, but I wonder why that should make a difference anyway) nor can transforming a date object that is dependant on the browser implementation be of any help in the first place. When the date object is not the same, you can do whatever you want with it and it will still not be the same.

Comment: Being bound to the browser implementation is wrong in the first place indeed, it is preferable to use a formatter of your own that will pick the individual pieces but in all cases I've tried for the exception of IE which simply takes the date as-is without timezone calculations

I could say moment.js is a great library for handling it